# Avoid losing format after selecting all text and start typing

Tags: tinymce, wysiwyg, tinymce-4

We use TinyMCE as the wysiwyg editor for our content builder. You can drag and drop a text module and once you click an edit button an TinyMCE instance will open. This works really well.

Problem is now that the builder is made for designers so a lot of the times you add a text module just for a 1 word heading or other cases where you only have one block. (one h1, one p etc.) You can also see this behavior in the official demos: Just add an lonely h2 heading, select all text and start to write.

Now Tiny MCE has the default behavior that if you select the complete text (which is almost always the case if you for example change an 1 line / word heading) and you start typing you will lose your formats completely. ( in our case: color, font-size, font-weight, line-height etc.)

This makes editing an heading for example really painful. Best workaround so far is to leave 1 character to not lose the format and then delete the character in the end.

I never saw that behavior in other editors so my question is: Is there maybe an easy setting or workaround to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

If there are situations where you want a root element to be something specific (e.g. `<h2>`) you can use the `forced_root_block` setting on that instance of TinyMCE to force a specific element:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#forced_root_block

Even if you delete all text the new text will be wrapped with that root element.  See this TinyMCE Fiddle for examples:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/SOfaab

I think this would address your one line issue?